# Plot fractals with rectangle background

Tags: pine-script

I'm new to Pine Script in Tradingview.

I am trying to plot the Williams Fractal indicator as a shaded box from a down fractal across to the next up fractal then down to the next down fractal and so on. There is a link to an image of what I am trying to do.

[exampleboxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/faIgr.jpg)

After 30+ attempts I am reaching out to get some assistance if you can.

This is the code for the fractals

```
//@version=4
study("Williams Fractals", shorttitle="Fractals", format=format.price, precision=0, overlay=true)
// Define "n" as the number of periods and keep a minimum value of 2 for error handling.
n = input(title="Periods", defval=2, minval=2, type=input.integer)

upFractal = (                                                                                                          (high[n+2]  < high[n]) and (high[n+1]  < high[n]) and (high[n-1] < high[n]) and (high[n-2] < high[n]))
         or (                                                                               (high[n+3]  < high[n]) and (high[n+2]  < high[n]) and (high[n+1] == high[n]) and (high[n-1] < high[n]) and (high[n-2] < high[n]))
         or (                                                    (high[n+4]  < high[n]) and (high[n+3]  < high[n]) and (high[n+2] == high[n]) and (high[n+1] <= high[n]) and (high[n-1] < high[n]) and (high[n-2] < high[n]))
         or (                          (high[n+5] < high[n]) and (high[n+4]  < high[n]) and (high[n+3] == high[n]) and (high[n+2] == high[n]) and (high[n+1] <= high[n]) and (high[n-1] < high[n]) and (high[n-2] < high[n]))
         or ((high[n+6] < high[n]) and (high[n+5] < high[n]) and (high[n+4] == high[n]) and (high[n+3] <= high[n]) and (high[n+2] == high[n]) and (high[n+1] <= high[n]) and (high[n-1] < high[n]) and (high[n-2] < high[n]))

dnFractal = (                                                                                                  (low[n+2]  > low[n]) and (low[n+1]  > low[n]) and (low[n-1] > low[n]) and (low[n-2] > low[n]))
         or (                                                                         (low[n+3]  > low[n]) and (low[n+2]  > low[n]) and (low[n+1] == low[n]) and (low[n-1] > low[n]) and (low[n-2] > low[n]))
         or (                                                (low[n+4]  > low[n]) and (low[n+3]  > low[n]) and (low[n+2] == low[n]) and (low[n+1] >= low[n]) and (low[n-1] > low[n]) and (low[n-2] > low[n]))
         or (                        (low[n+5] > low[n]) and (low[n+4]  > low[n]) and (low[n+3] == low[n]) and (low[n+2] == low[n]) and (low[n+1] >= low[n]) and (low[n-1] > low[n]) and (low[n-2] > low[n]))
         or ((low[n+6] > low[n]) and (low[n+5] > low[n]) and (low[n+4] == low[n]) and (low[n+3] >= low[n]) and (low[n+2] == low[n]) and (low[n+1] >= low[n]) and (low[n-1] > low[n]) and (low[n-2] > low[n]))

// Plot the fractals as shapes on the chart.
plotshape(dnFractal, style=shape.triangledown, location=location.belowbar, offset=-2, color=color.maroon, transp=0)
plotshape(upFractal, style=shape.triangleup,   location=location.abovebar, offset=-2, color=color.olive,  transp=0)
```

If you can give me any pointers, I would appreciate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not too sure what you have in mind with your *shaded box*, but this may give you ideas. Add it at the end of your code:

```
var float hiBase = na
var float loBase = na
// Remember hi/lo of new fractal as it is identified, 
// and ignore new opposite fractal when dual fractals are identified on same bar.
if upFractal and not dnFractal
    hiBase := high[n]
    loBase := na
if dnFractal and not upFractal
    hiBase := na
    loBase := low[n]
// Use the fact that we are plotting hiBase=na or loBase=na when we don't need one of the fills.
// Make special cases at new fractal to continue plotting previous fractal fill for another bar.
hi1 = plot(na(loBase[1]) and not na(loBase) ? hiBase[1] : hiBase, color = color.white, transp = 100, offset=-n)
hi2 = plot(low[n], color = color.white, transp = 100, offset=-n)
fill( hi1, hi2, color = color.red)
lo1 = plot(na(hiBase[1]) and not na(hiBase) ? loBase[1] : loBase, color = color.white, transp = 100, offset=-n)
lo2 = plot(high[n], color = color.white, transp = 100, offset=-n)
fill( lo1, lo2, color = color.green)
```

[EDIT 2019.08.21 21:32 — LucF]

```
plotchar(dnFractal, "", "⌄", location=location.belowbar, offset=-n, color=color.maroon, transp=0, size=size.small)
plotchar(upFractal, "", "⌃", location=location.abovebar, offset=-n, color=color.olive, transp=0, size=size.small)

var float hiBase = na
var float loBase = na
if upFractal and not dnFractal
    hiBase := high[n]
if dnFractal and not upFractal
    loBase := low[n]
hi = plot(hiBase, color=color.white, transp=100, offset=-n, style=plot.style_linebr)
lo = plot(loBase, color=color.white, transp=100, offset=-n, style=plot.style_linebr)
fill(hi, lo, color=color.gray)
```

Comment: Thanks LucF. That helps me a lot.
 
Ideally I would keep the shading at the level of the previous down fractal until a new down fractal was formed. And similarly at the level of the previous up fractal until a new up fractal was formed. 

I will have a play and see if I can make it happen.

Any suggestions would be gratefully received though.
Thanks Again.

Comment: I have added an image in my original post to show what I am trying to do. 
Cheers

Comment: Edited answer with something more like the example, and Unicode arrows you may want to use.

Comment: That is brilliant @LucF - PineCoders Thank you so much.

Comment: ) If you consider the question answered, you can click the check mark under the voting arrows for this answer.